# Duplicate messages are being sent by kafka Producer after enabling transaction

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a very simple program where I am iterating through a lop of 10 and sending message to a kafka topic. I have put a sysout to check how many times the send is actually called. IT always prints but when I check the number of messages in kafka topic it is 18.

PSB code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "Producer");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9097,localhost:9098");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    KafkaProducer<Integer, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    producer.initTransactions();

    producer.beginTransaction();
    try {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Sending i -->" + i);
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("TopicIn3", i, "Simple Message-T1-" + i));
        }
        producer.commitTransaction();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        producer.abortTransaction();
        producer.close();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Logs :

```
Sending i -->1
Sending i -->2
Sending i -->3
Sending i -->4
Sending i -->5
Sending i -->6
Sending i -->7
Sending i -->8
Sending i -->9
Sending i -->10
```

count from topic:

```
> sh kafka_installation/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9098  --topic TopicIn3 --time -1 
TopicIn3:0:2
TopicIn3:1:2
TopicIn3:2:0
TopicIn3:3:4
TopicIn3:4:0
TopicIn3:5:0
TopicIn3:6:2
TopicIn3:7:0
TopicIn3:8:2
TopicIn3:9:0
TopicIn3:10:0
TopicIn3:11:2
TopicIn3:12:0
TopicIn3:13:0
TopicIn3:14:2
TopicIn3:15:0
TopicIn3:16:0
TopicIn3:17:0
TopicIn3:18:0
TopicIn3:19:2
```

Comment: How many messages come out when you try to consume them with a consumer?

Comment: hi Yassin .. I lost that topic .. but i ran with new topic.. this time the command gave me 14 outputs but the consumer reads only 10 messages ( from 1 to 10).

Comment: do 2 things: 1- set up your Kafka to follow the 'exactly-once'  config. 2- in your consumer use `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest"`, and spin up your consumer first before producing a message.

Comment: It'd also help if you pasted your Consumer code snippet in the question also.